# IIS 8.5 Redirect a subfolder to the same on new subdomain

Tags: iis, http-status-code-301, redirect, http-redirect

Trying to 301 redirect traffic from:

www.domain.com/directory/

to

new.domain.com/directory/

It also needs to redirect:

www.domain.com/directory/dynamicallygeneratednames.html

to

new.domain.com/directory/dynamicallygeneratednames.html

I can make the first work easy enough but the second bit I just can't find the correct settings in the url rewrite or the http redirection modules in IIS. The full urls aren't actually files they are dynamically generated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [IIS URL Redirect Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and here is [how to use it](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

then you will have to use some regex to separate parts of the original url

so lets consider www.domain.com/directory/whatever/comes/here/of/any/lengths

you can use this ^(/directory)(/.*)? regex pattern in iis redirect module to separate /directory  and /whatever/comes/here/of/any/lengths into two chunks
{R:1} & {R:2} or {C:1} & {C:2} [depends how you use it]

then your final redirect should look like where you chose the new domain, /directory is matched and rest of the url gets transferred over

new.domain.com/{R:1}{R:2} or newdomain.com{C:1}{C:2}